# resolving this simple php math

Tags: php

I am trying to get multiple number  of 2 and 3 pls help. Thanks

```
for($i = 0; $i <30; $i++) 
if($i % 2)
echo 'number is '. $i . ' is multiple of 2 <br/>';
elseif($i %3)
echo 'number is '. $i . 'is multiple of 3 <br/>';
else
echo 'number is '. $i . 'is multiple of some other number <br/>';
```

Comment: What about 6, how will you treat that? And what's 17 a multiple of?

Comment: @Kerrek 17 is a multiple of 1 and 17, so the last statement is still valid. But you brought up a good point about 6

Comment: 6 is also a multiple of 1. Hmm. And 15? That's also a multiple of 5, i.e. "some other number".

Comment: Is this homework and you must use modulus? Otherwise, it would be far preferable to simply have two loops: one that counted by 2's and the other that counted by 3's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($i % 2 === 0)
  ...
elseif($i %3 === 0)
  ...
```

Basically if the modulo is `0` then that means the number is evenly divisible.

However, another problem with your logic is that a number may be divisible by both `2` and `3`. You can fix this by extracting these out into separate `if` statements:

```
if($i %2 === 0) {
  ... 
}

if($i %3 === 0) {
  ... 
}
```

But that sort of breaks your last `else` since you cannot just fall though to it anymore. You could solve that by setting a variable to `false` at the top of your loop. Then if any of your `if` statements is triggered, set the variable to `true`. Finally, print the "not divisible" message at the end of each iteration if the variable is still `false`.

Comment: it's nearly giving my answer but is problem when number is multiple of both 2 and 3; number is 0 is multiple of 2
number is 1is multiple of some other number
number is 2 is multiple of 2
number is 3is multiple of 3
number is 4 is multiple of 2
number is 5is multiple of some other number
number is 6 is multiple of 2
number is 7is multiple of some other number
number is 8 is multiple of 2
number is 9is multiple of 3
number is 10 is multiple of 2
number is 11is multiple of some other number
number is 12 is multiple of 2

Answer (score 1):

You want a NOT if(i%2) because it is a multiple if the remainder is zero.

Additionally if you're trying to find multiples of 30 you only need to loop up to 15. Or number/2.

Comment: your Additionally isn't applicable here, as that's not the goal

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) 
{
if($i % 2 == 0)
    echo 'number is '. $i . ' is multiple of 2 <br/>';
elseif($i % 3 == 0)
    echo 'number is '. $i . 'is multiple of 3 <br/>';
else
    echo 'number is '. $i . 'is multiple of some other number <br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more condition before your if conditions

```
if($i%2 === 0 && $i%3 === 0) {
    echo 'multiple of 2 and 3\n';
}
```

It may also be correct to use:

```
if ($i%6 === 0) {
 ....
}
```

for the above if condition.

Even better if you use a switch case block.